# SSIS data tool toolbox fix

Tags: ssis, toolbox

I make integration service project using data tools Visual Studio .  I have encountered with  a problem.   There are no toolbox elements on the menu  in  data tool Visual Studio. I want to return it back in order to make my project . I have reset default settings but it didn't help .  Also I have the feeling that my project opens in the Visual Studio  environment instead of SQl server  data tools . I upload screenshot as well

Comment: Screen shots are not available for me

Comment: Screenshot pls.

Answer (score 0):

This can be confusing as sometimes you will see the normal toolbox that appear empty as you are not working on a UI such as windows forms.  There is a menu item SSIS, under that is SSIS toolbox.